# LLVM FunctionCall

Tags: string, parameter-passing, llvm, llvm-ir

I started working with LLVM recently and I have a problem with inserting a function in my IR Code.
At first my function was just like this:

```
print(){
     printf("Hello")
  }
```

And I managed to insert it before every CALL instruction with this code :

```
Function *fun;
for (Module::iterator F = M.begin(), E = M.end(); F != E; ++F) {
 if (F->getName() == "print") {       
    fun= cast<Function>(F);
}
for (Function::iterator BB = F->begin(), E = F->end(); BB != E; ++BB) {

          for (BasicBlock::iterator BI = BB->begin(), BE = BB->end(); BI != BE; ++BI) {

           if (isa<CallInst>(&(*BI))) {
              CallInst *CI = dyn_cast<CallInst>(BI);
              Instruction *newInst = CallInst::Create(fun, "");
              BB->getInstList().insert(BI, newInst);

            }
          }
 }
```

Now I am trying to do this same thing (inserting my print function before every call instruction) but my print function must be this type of function :

```
void print (string something){
   printf ("hello");
   do something with "something" string but whatever;
}
```

I tried everything I found without success...
(I don't understand how is working IRBuiler, createGlobalString/Ptr, and getOrInsertFunction() and it must be my problem... Can Someone help me? Thank you...

Answer (score 0):

The way to instrument such a function call is like

```
CallInst* callonFree = CallInst::Create(your_print_fun, {CI->getOperand(0)},"",CI);
```

Usually you can try to convert your string to a char*, which would be simpler to instrument.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I used a char* and it was easier !